# Python BeautifulSoup MySQL storage and interation

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

First, there is a leading "1" in the return string and I'm encountering trouble iterating passed it - I've tried using [0:]: method and get stuck somewhere. I'd like to skip drop it or skip it to get to the second value that is the id val. the scraped table

Additionally, in trying to format returned items from table for storage - I've been getting index out of range errors. I've been using def store().

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb

#mysql portion
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='****',
   user= '****',
   passwd='****',
   db='****')
cur = mydb.cursor()
def store (id, ticker):
    cur.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO TEST (id, ticker) VALUES (\"%s\", \"%s\")',(id, ticker))
    cur.connection.commit()

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,24,25,63,64,65,66,67'
html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'screener-content'})
table = main_div.find('table')
sub = table.findAll('tr')
cells = sub[5].findAll('td')

for cell in cells:
    link = cell.a
    if link is not None:
    link = link.get_text()
        id = link[0]
        ticker = link[1]
        store(id, ticker)
    print(link)
```

Comment: what `"return string"` ? where/how do you get this "return string" ?

Comment: you define `link = []`, later you overwrite it with `link = cell.a`, later you get string `link = link.get_text()` but you treat it as list `id = link[0]`, `ticker = link[1]`. What do you try to do ?

Comment: - removed the redundant link =[], when I comment out the link-list items I get a the link.a data - In an effort to save the data I convereted into list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you real try to do but this works for me

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,24,25,63,64,65,66,67'

html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")

rows = soup.find_all('tr', class_=["table-dark-row-cp", "table-light-row-cp"])

for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td')

    id_ = columns[0].a.get_text()
    ticker = columns[1].a.get_text()
    company = columns[2].a.get_text()
    sector = columns[3].a.get_text()
    industry = columns[4].a.get_text()

    print(id_, ticker, company, sector, industry)
```

Or event with `a`

```
for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('a')

    id_ = columns[0].get_text()
    ticker = columns[1].get_text()
    company = columns[2].get_text()
    sector = columns[3].get_text()
    industry = columns[4].get_text()

    print(id_, ticker, company, sector, industry)
```

---

**BTW:** you can also use `CSS` selector

```
rows = soup.select('#screener-content table[bgcolor="#d3d3d3"] tr[class]')
```

or

```
rows = soup.select('#screener-content table[bgcolor="#d3d3d3"] tr')
# skip first row with headers
rows = rows[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input I hadn't considered using the "table-dark-row-cp" tags since it pulls every other item. Could I use an "and" to get both "table-dark..." and "table-light..." items?

Comment: `class_=["table-dark-row-cp", "table-light-row-cp"]`

Comment: list - of course. I was just working on that - thanks a bunch!

Comment: see also example with `CSS` selector